# XLST - Copy XML tag and replace attribute value

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, sed

I have the following XML file:

```
<config>
  <connection port="4404" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4405" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4406" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>

  <option>
    <maxNumberOfDownloads>10</maxNumberOfDownload>
  </option>
  
</config>
```

I would like to copy the connection tags, paste them after the `</option>` tag and replace the first 2 digits of the port to have something like this

```
<config>
  <connection port="4404" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode1" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4405" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode2" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4406" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode3" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>

  <option>
    <maxNumberOfDownloads>10</maxNumberOfDownload>
  </option>

  <connection port="7804" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode1" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="7805" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode2" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="7806" type="tcp">
      <selection name="test-mode3" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  
</config>
```

**Any hints on how this could be achieved?**

Comment: How about XSLT?

Comment: Absolutely ! I'm actually looking into this possibility. I'm opened for this option but I'm very novice with XLST.

Comment: The desired file is no valid XML. Is this intended?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes this is intended. These are properties files used within the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT based solution.

**Input XML**

```
<config>
    <connection port="4404" type="tcp">
        <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
    </connection>
    <connection port="4405" type="tcp">
        <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
    </connection>
    <connection port="4406" type="tcp">
        <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
    </connection>

    <option>
        <maxNumberOfDownloads>10</maxNumberOfDownloads>
    </option>
</config>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="connection[@port]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="port">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('78', substring(@port,3,2))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<config>
  <connection port="4404" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="7804" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4405" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="7805" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="4406" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <connection port="7806" type="tcp">
    <selection name="test-mode" enabled="true"/>
  </connection>
  <option>
    <maxNumberOfDownloads>10</maxNumberOfDownloads>
  </option>
</config>
```